# $A$ and $B$ connected, but $A \setminus B$ not connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Im trying to find $A$ and $B$ connected, but $A \setminus B$ not connected in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I think if we take $A = \mathbb{R}^2$ is connected and $B = \{ y = 1 \}$ connected but $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ y=1 \}$ is not connected. How can I show this set is not connected? Im having such a hard time with it.

Comment: One approach would be to continuously map $A\backslash B$ to a two-point set, say $\{+1,-1\}$, which is obviously disconnected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A set if not connected if it is the union of two disjoint nonempty open sets. Now note that $$\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{y =1 \} = \underbrace{\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y >1\}}_A \cup \overbrace{\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y <1\}}^B$$
All you need to show is that $A$ and $B$ are open.